# find text cointain in folder name and skip it's

Tags: loops, ffmpeg, find

```
for subdir in */ ; do
cd $subdir
ffmpeg -i mycode
```

how do I exclude the ffmpeg command if the folder name contains foo?

i use command find, is correctly?

```
find . -name *foo* -print
```

but I can not implement it in bash for loop.

I tried this code:

```
for subdir in */ ; do
foo=$(find -type d -name '*foo*')
if [[ $subdir =~ $foo ] ; then
    echo yes
    ffmpeg -i mycode
else
    echo no
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly Tadly's version with unnecessary quotes removed:

```
foo="your string"
for subdir in */
do
    if [[ $subdir != *$foo* ]]
    then
        echo ffmpeg -i "$subdir"...
    else
        echo skipping $subdir
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use * at the beginning and at the end of the $foo variable like so:

```
foo="your_string"
for subdir in */; do
        if [[ "$subdir" == *"$foo"* ]]; then
                echo "$subdir - includes $foo"
        else
                echo "$subdir - does not include $foo"
        fi
done;
```